# Построение REST API запросов yii2

Tags: yii2, rest, postman

yii2, пишу апи REST API, тестирую в postman.

yii2 строит запросы так: `example.com/controller/id`.

postman строит запросы так :  `example.com/controller?id=id`.

как привести их к единому виду?

если менять что-то в приложении yii, то надо сделать так, чтобы чпу остались.

Comment: А почему вы не пишите unit тесты с использованием, например, guzzle ?

Comment: @ArchDemon, потому что нету опыта разработки как такового, и нету опыта написания и тестирования собственного api. да и ,если я правильно понял, сопоставление postman и guzzle это как сопоставление мягкого и теплого.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ну, пока нету полноценного решения, делаю так:

просто не указывая параметры в постмане делаю запросы прямо на ссылку. т.е. в строке запроса ссылка вида `example/controller/id`